# Blue border around Kendo Tabstrip

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-tabstrip

I have this annoying blue border around the Kendo Tabstrip whenever it is selected.

Possibly something to do with aria?

[image]

Does anyone know how to remove it?

Comment: Show us your code by editing the question.

Answer (score 3):

The kendo css includes a box shadow when the tabstrip has focus. You can override it by adding the following css:

```
.k-tabstrip:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome I have been looking for this for like a hour!